# IntelliJ: Scala sbt sync failed

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have added Scalacheck to my `build.sbt` It looks like this:

```
name := "$name"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.6"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.14.0" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test"
```

Now IntelliJ reports "sync failed", when I try to 'File -> Synchronize'.
There is no Scalacheck under external libraries. Compiling the tests results in: "Symbol 'term org.scalacheck' is missing from class path".

- Auto Import Scala is on.
- Java is JDK 10.0.1.
- Scala is 2.12.6
- Scala Plugin is 2018.01.09

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the context around where you inserted that line? Maybe it's a syntax error.

Comment: Also, if you remove that line, does syncing work again?

Comment: No. Removing the line does not help. Doesn't sync without either.

Comment: If you execute 'sbt upddate' in a terminal, what does sbt log when resolving the dependency?

Comment: It's weird that pulling that line back out doesn't fix the issue. I'd be inclined to go back to the original build.sbt that was working, "refresh sbt project," and if that still doesn't work, bounce intellij, since it sounds like there's more going on than a simple bad sbt.

Comment: please provide the log for the failed sync. also, does this reproduce with any other project?